# How to connect mysql database to Firebase

Tags: android, mysql, firebase

I have an app using a mysql database. The thing is that i would like the app to detect each time a new row is inserted in the database to have realtime updated data.
I heard about Firebase and its realtime sync database and i would like to know how to connect my mysql database to it.
If it can't be done, how could I achieve this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Firebase store data in  json format so you have to convert your mysql database in json format before using firebase

Comment: Hi @saurabhdixit. Thanks for your quick answer.
How could I do such a thing? What should I do after such a conversion?

Comment: you have to  import that json file in firebase project's database, which you have created and can start using that following these steps given here https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use Firebase to detect every time a new row is inserted in a MySQL database. What can you do instead, is to check your MySQL database for new rows, and every time a new row is inserted, add that data to Firebase.

Another approach will be to transform the MySQL database in a Firebase database which is a real-time database. For this, I recommend you see this tutorial, [The Firebase Database For SQL Developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: Do I have to set up a trigger for that?

Comment: Yes, you can set a trigger for that, then get the data, then insert in Firebase. But i recomand you using for that only Firebase.

Comment: I can't use only Firebase as my app is already built and the mysql database required.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think it doesn't make sense to use MySQL and Firebase together. If you want to get real time data I suggest you to use only Firebase. Firebase also offers automatic mechanisms for authentication and stores JSON which really give you flexibility with data structure. On the other hand if you don't want to use Firebase and stick to MySQL you can implement a service on client side that we request data from server every 5 minutes for example.

Comment: But such a solution would take lots of ressources don't you think?

Comment: Of course if you want to stick with MySQL. It depends on you, to be honest I wouldn't use MySQL if I want real time application. I would use Firebase or Mongo which are more suitable technologies for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Better you should go for only firebase database. Connecting firebase with MySQL is not possible. And make more complexities.